# Cannot refer to local variable

Tags: java, android

I'm new to the world of Android programming and I want to, when a button is clicked, to do stuff. Here's what I did so far:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {


        Spinner s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7;
        TextView txt3,txt4,txt5,txt6,txt7,txt8,txt9;
        EditText ed1;

        s7 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner7);
        s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        s2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        s3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
        s4 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner4);
        s5 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner5);
        s6 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner6);
        txt4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        txt3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        txt5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        txt6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
        txt7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
        txt8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);
        txt9 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView9);


        ed1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);


        s7.setOnItemSelectedListener(
                new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    public void onItemSelected(
                            AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                            String val = s7.getSelectedItem().toString();
                            txt4.setText(val);

                    }


                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                    }
                });
        s2.setOnItemSelectedListener(
                new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    public void onItemSelected(
                            AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                            String val2 = s2.getSelectedItem().toString();
                            txt5.setText(val2);

                    }


                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                    }
                });
        s3.setOnItemSelectedListener(
                new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    public void onItemSelected(
                            AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                            String val3 = s3.getSelectedItem().toString();
                            txt6.setText(val3);

                    }


                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                    }
                });
        s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(
                new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    public void onItemSelected(
                            AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                            String val1 = s1.getSelectedItem().toString();
                            txt3.setText(val1);

                    }


                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                    }
                });
        s5.setOnItemSelectedListener(
                new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    public void onItemSelected(
                            AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                            String val5 = s5.getSelectedItem().toString();
                            txt7.setText(val5);

                    }


                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                    }
                });
        s6.setOnItemSelectedListener(
                new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    public void onItemSelected(
                            AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                            String val6 = s6.getSelectedItem().toString();
                            txt8.setText(val6);

                    }


                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                    }
                });
        s4.setOnItemSelectedListener(
                new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    public void onItemSelected(
                            AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                            String val7 = s4.getSelectedItem().toString();
                            txt9.setText(val7);

                    }


                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                    }
                });




    }}    //Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
}}
```

however,all my variable in the code(s1,s2,txt1,txt2,...) get the error "Cannot refer to the non-final local variable [var] defined in an enclosing scope'' and I get the error "Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement" at place indicated on code.Can anybody help me solve this?

thank you!

Comment: Why are you putting your onitemselected listeners inside your onclick listener?

Comment: What is supposed to happen when you click your button?

Comment: s7.setOnItemSelectedListener(
                new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    public void onItemSelected(
                            AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                            String val = s7.getSelectedItem().toString();
                            txt4.setText(val);

                    }  and the rest until the end

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, because there are local variables and you called them from an [anonymous class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html); you have just to declare them as properties of the class.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Spinner s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7;
    TextView txt3,txt4,txt5,txt6,txt7,txt8,txt9;
    // The rest of your code
```

Comment: @Phil_oneil Add a right paren + semicolon to close your assignment. More importantly (and as already asked), why are you doing this inside the click listener?

Comment: When you called button.setOnClickListener, you forgot to close the function call. button.setOnClickListener(new ... );

Comment: @Krylez I want to make all the onitemselectedlistener to happen when I click the button im trying stuff how to properly do that then?

Comment: You're adding new listeners _every_ time the button is clicked. After the first click, this is just wasteful because the new listeners do the _exact_ same thing as the ones that are already assigned to the Spinners. The assignment should occur at the same level that the button listener assignment does.

Comment: I am not saying this to be rude, but you really should understand how [scope](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0020__Language/VariableScope.htm) works _before_ asking others to help you with problems like this.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your local variables as your class variables and then you also need to complete the OnClickListener() method properly at the end of it. You need to close the method with the closing parenthesis and semicolon at the syntax error.

Comment: what do you mean? I did it and the error still there

Answer (score 0):

Three suggestions:

1. Be consistent with formatting and indentation in your code.
2. Use arrays.
3. Create a single `OnItemClickListener` and reuse it for all of your spinners.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to access a variable outside of an annonymous class, it must have to be `final`. 
Your code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        final Spinner s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7;
        final TextView txt3,txt4,txt5,txt6,txt7,txt8,txt9;
        final EditText ed1;

        s7 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner7);
        s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        s2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        s3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
        s4 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner4);
        s5 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner5);
        s6 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner6);
        txt4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        txt3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        txt5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        txt6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
        txt7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
        txt8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);
        txt9 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView9);


        ed1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {






                s7.setOnItemSelectedListener(
                        new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                            public void onItemSelected(
                                    AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                                String val = s7.getSelectedItem().toString();
                                txt4.setText(val);

                            }


                            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                            }
                        });
                s2.setOnItemSelectedListener(
                        new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                            public void onItemSelected(
                                    AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                                String val2 = s2.getSelectedItem().toString();
                                txt5.setText(val2);

                            }


                            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                            }
                        });
                s3.setOnItemSelectedListener(
                        new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                            public void onItemSelected(
                                    AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                                String val3 = s3.getSelectedItem().toString();
                                txt6.setText(val3);

                            }


                            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                            }
                        });
                s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(
                        new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                            public void onItemSelected(
                                    AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                                String val1 = s1.getSelectedItem().toString();
                                txt3.setText(val1);

                            }


                            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                            }
                        });
                s5.setOnItemSelectedListener(
                        new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                            public void onItemSelected(
                                    AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                                String val5 = s5.getSelectedItem().toString();
                                txt7.setText(val5);

                            }


                            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                            }
                        });
                s6.setOnItemSelectedListener(
                        new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                            public void onItemSelected(
                                    AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                                String val6 = s6.getSelectedItem().toString();
                                txt8.setText(val6);

                            }


                            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                            }
                        });
                s4.setOnItemSelectedListener(
                        new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                            public void onItemSelected(
                                    AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                                String val7 = s4.getSelectedItem().toString();
                                txt9.setText(val7);

                            }


                            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                            }
                        });




            }});    //Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to when I click the button the s7.setOnItemSelectedListener( to happen(that pu content of spinner in textview). it crash when I click the button with your code.thanks

Answer (score 0):

Although other answers have suggested making your variables class variables, there is another way to solve the first error: add `final` to the declarations.

```
final Spinner s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7;
final TextView txt3,txt4,txt5,txt6,txt7,txt8,txt9;
```

When you add `final` to the declarations, and you don't give them initial values, Java will let you assign to them once, but then the values are "fixed" and you can't assign to them any more.  It's necessary to use `final` variables if they're referred to from an anonymous type such as you're using.  (This is because Java wants to make sure the variables won't change after you create the listener object.  If they could change, then there could be confusion about "is it supposed to use the value that the variable had when the listener was created, or is it supposed to use the latest value?")

In general, it's best to declare variables at the innermost scope where they're used.  That's why I don't like the solution of simply making them class variables.  That solution gets rid of the error but is inferior from a "clean code" perspective.  And since it's easy enough to just make the variables `final`, making them class variables is not necessary, unless you really *intend* for them to be part of the `MainActivity`'s state.

The reason for the `;` error is that at the very top of your code snippet, you say

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
    --followed by lots and lots of code--
```

Since you have so much code in your listener, it's easy to lose track of where the statement beings and ends.  But the above statement has to have correct syntax like any other statement, which means it has to have the form

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { [code] });
```

That is, you have to have the closing curly brace, followed by the closing `)` that matches the `(` just before `new`, followed by a semicolon.

**P.S.** You have a lot of duplicated code in the `onSelectedItem` listeners; once you get things to work, you may want to simplify things.  It's possible to write a private method that creates and returns a listener:

```
private AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener listenerForSpinner(final Spinner s, final TextView t) {
    return new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
         public void onItemSelected(
             AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

             String val = s.getSelectedItem().toString();
             t.setText(val);
         }

         public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
         }
    };
}
```

and in the `SetOnClickListener`:

```
s7.setOnItemSelectedListener(listenerForSpinner(s7, txt4));
s2.setOnItemSelectedListener(listenerForSpinner(s2, txt5));
...
```

and so on, which makes your code much simpler.  (But using arrays, as already suggested, would simplify even more.)

Comment: but will that make the s7.onitemselected...and the rest(wich place element of spinner in textview) to happen when I click the button? this is what I want it to do im not sure if it does that.. thank you

Comment: @Phil_oneil I was focusing on getting the code to compile, not on getting it to work.  If it doesn't work and nobody else has answered that, I'll take another look.

Comment: That would be really helpful because I dont know how to do so

Comment: @Phil_oneil I think this will do what you want, if I understand what you want.  When you click the button, `s7.onItemSelected` will register a listener for the spinner.  So if you click the button and then select the `spinner7` spinner, it will call the code in that listener, which gets the string and calls `setText`.  If it's crashing, please start a new question, and provide the stack backtrace from the `logcat`.

Comment: when I click the button,I want it to call ALL the sx.onitemselected, they all have to execute

Comment: @Phil_oneil Right, they all will.  Sorry, I should have been clearer about that.  P.S. If the program crashes, the first thing to do is to make sure `s1`, `s2`, ..., aren't `null`.  `findViewById` can return `null` if things aren't set up correctly.

Comment: I tried applying your code but when I click the button nothing happen? could you apply if to my code? I dont get it. thanks a lot

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing happens"?  Calling `onItemSelected` won't have any visible effect, until you actually select something.  Are you saying that `onItemSelected` isn't called?  How do you know?  Anyway, this has gotten too far from your original question, so I think you'll need to start a new question if you continue to have problems.  Also please keep in mind that there's a limit to how much StackOverflow can help you debug your own code.

Comment: I mean that when I launch it on android emulator tablet, the element in spinner are not going in the text views when I click the button; they go in the textview as I change the elements in spinner, but they go in the textview automatically,without having to click the button